# Django - initial checked CheckboxInput

Tags: django, django-templates

I want my CheckboxInput was checked by default :

**My models :**

```
class Sub(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    batata = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class presentationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta : 
        model = Sub
    widgets = {
        'batata': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'id':'batata'}),
    }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.valbata = kwargs.pop("arg_bata")
        super(presentationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['batata'].initial = True
```

**My view :**

```
def theview(request):
    form = presentationForm(arg_bata="Azerty")
    return render(request,"le_site/page-batata.html",locals())
```

**My template :**

```
<div id="mod">
    {% load bootstrap %}
    <form method="POST" id="formModificationFic">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.batata|bootstrap }}
     ...
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" id="le_bouton" value="Confirmer">
            </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

**My JS :**

```
function envoie_post(){
   var batataRep = document.getElementById("batata").checked;
   alert("batataRep : "+batataRep);  
   $.post("http://localhost:8000/page-batata",  "batataRep":batataRep});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formModificationFic").submit(function() {
        envoie_post();
        return false;
    });
});
```

But in my page, the checbkoxInput "batata" isn't checked...
And I think the JS hasn't effects

Comment: Hi. I have tried to help you once and I am here again) I have copied all your code and run it. Also installed https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form and the result is as expected. It's checked. What else is in your template? Do you have any js code on frontend?

Comment: O_O... Yes I have a js, wait ;)

Comment: It's not checked when you just open the page, right? Cause with this update it's also checked for me. I see that you have other fields in your form. Can you try to remove them from form and check whether it works with one boolean field in form?

Comment: according to your comment about `checked="checked"` I think your css code have problems. You should review it using devtools and see whether there is no overriding for :checked state of inputs or something similar.

Comment: alalala, yes I create a js method a long time ago and I forget. This method dechecked all checkbox... Thank you very very much for today and yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Add **'checked'** attribute to your **Checkbox Input field** widget in **presentationForm**. So that your code becomes :

```
class presentationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta : 
    model = Sub
    widgets = {
    'batata': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'id':'batata', 'checked' : ''}),
}
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.valbata = kwargs.pop("arg_bata")
    super(presentationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['batata'].initial = True
```

Comment: When I open source code, It's write that field is checked "checked="checked"" but isn't visible...

Comment: Try removing the following line.
'self.fields['batata'].initial = True'